# Can i send emails without Email plan

Tags: email, dns, smtp, hosting

1 Insert A record with Live IP (where i bought the domain)
2 Insert MX record (where i bought the domain)
3 insert Cname (where i bought the domain)
4 Install my own SMTP server on windows and assign Live IP (on my local network)

is it enough or some more settings will be needed?

I tried Upper all setting but i am receiving outbound emails but can't send email to other domain.
i am receiving error message.

`550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Helo domain is listed in Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/lookup/`

I want to just confirm that upper setting are enough which i did or some other setting
will be needed.
do i have to configure bellow configurations?
1 DNS. on window and setup lookup zone and reverse zone
2 IIS. Configurations